# Oracle query to check for failure more than 90 %

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I need to write a monitoring query to run every 2 hour to raise alert when processed count becomes less than 90%.

Lets say we have a Table Incoming Message where all incoming messages are captured and another table where all processed messages are captured.

This is what I came up with, this works but I am wondering if there is better way of doing this?

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PROCESSEDCOUNT <= INCOMINGCOUNT * .9 
THEN 'ALERT:: Process Count ' || PROCESSEDCOUNT || ' is less than 90% of Incoming count ' || INCOMINGCOUNT || '. '
ELSE 'FINE:: Process Count ' || PROCESSEDCOUNT || ' is more than or equal to 90% of Incoming count ' || INCOMINGCOUNT || '. '
END ) as Status
from 
(SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INCOMING_TABLE D WHERE INSERTION_TIME > SYSDATE - (1/12) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PROCESSED_TABLE C WHERE ( D.MESSAGE_ID = C.MESSAGE_ID)
AND C.PROCESSED_TIME > SYSDATE- (1/12))) AS PROCESSEDCOUNT,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INCOMING_TABLE WHERE INSERTION_TIME > SYSDATE - (1/12)) AS INCOMINGCOUNT
FROM DUAL);
```

- PROCESSED_TABLE used for storing other records as well, that is the
  reason I need to use EXISTS to figure out process count.
- I understand as time captured in two tables may not fall into same
  time duration. We are not worried about that right now, just want to
  make sure majority of records processed.
- We are using oracle 11g, if that helps.

Comment: try DBMS_AQ built-in package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the same data from `INCOMING_TABLE` twice, which isn't really efficient ;-)

One possibility could be to outer join:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN COUNT(C.MESSAGE_ID) <= COUNT(*) * .9 
      THEN 'ALERT:: Process Count ' || COUNT(C.MESSAGE_ID) || ' is less than 90% of Incoming count ' || COUNT(*) || '. '
      ELSE 'FINE:: Process Count ' || COUNT(C.MESSAGE_ID) || ' is more than or equal to 90% of Incoming count ' || COUNT(*) || '. '
   END as Status
FROM INCOMING_TABLE D
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROCESSED_TABLE C
      ON C.MESSAGE_ID = D.MESSAGE_ID
     AND C.PROCESSED_TIME > SYSDATE- (1/12)
WHERE D.INSERTION_TIME > SYSDATE - (1/12)
/
```

That will work if you can be sure either zero or one record exists in `PROCESSED_TABLE` for each message_id. Maybe you can add a `AND C.PROCESS_TYPE = ...` or something to make that condition come true.

If you cannot guarantee that a join to `PROCESSED_TABLE` returns at most one row, you can move your `EXISTS` to inside a `COUNT` instead of the `WHERE` clause and thereby again avoid accessing `INCOMING_TABLE` twice:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PROCESSEDCOUNT <= INCOMINGCOUNT * .9 
THEN 'ALERT:: Process Count ' || PROCESSEDCOUNT || ' is less than 90% of Incoming count ' || INCOMINGCOUNT || '. '
ELSE 'FINE:: Process Count ' || PROCESSEDCOUNT || ' is more than or equal to 90% of Incoming count ' || INCOMINGCOUNT || '. '
END ) as Status
from 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) INCOMINGCOUNT
     , COUNT(
          CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PROCESSED_TABLE C
                          WHERE D.MESSAGE_ID = C.MESSAGE_ID
                          AND C.PROCESSED_TIME > SYSDATE- (1/12))
             THEN 1
          END
       ) PROCESSEDCOUNT
FROM INCOMING_TABLE D
WHERE D.INSERTION_TIME > SYSDATE - (1/12)
)
/
```

(PS. If you are at the start of writing a lot of code to handle a messaging queue, I would also suggest like @DARK_A to look into Advanced Queues instead of building your own. There is a lot of issues you need to handle in a messaging system, so why have that trouble if you can use what Oracle has already built ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out double fetching same data set and I liked your second solution.

Comment: A detail, but every time there's a reference to this or that column value should be more recent than sysdate minus something ... don't forget, that it is not impossible that future dates could be entered. I'll state again, it's very unlikely, but consider the chances.